# Erase certain messages in Messages on OS X

Tags: macos, messages

I like having the Messages app on my Mac, but I have one problem: When I delete a message thread on my iPhone, it doesn't delete from my Mac. In other words, if I delete three messages from the same person, on my phone, I see the previous messages and the later messages but not those specific ones. But on my Mac, they're all still there. And I don't see a place to delete them on my Mac the same way you delete them on the phone.

Answer (score 7):

Deleting messages on an iOS device doesn't delete them from any other device.

- You can remove message threads by clicking the × on the right of the contact.

  [image]
- You can remove individual messages by right-clicking the message and selecting Delete.

  [image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is certainly the case. If you have three devices that recieve messages (like I do) then messages must be deleted three separate times. :(

Answer (score 3):

There's an important detail missing in this answer, for those of you/us who are "click challenged".  The menu shown above (Forward...,Copy, Delete...) only shows up if you are clicking in the correct part of the message.  If you click over any of the words, you'll get a menu that looks like this[image]

If you instead click on an area of the message that has NO words, you'll get the menu shown in grgarside's post above.

Happy deleting!

Answer (score 0):

Hold control key while clicking on the message. Use the Delete option.

Answer (score 0):

On El Capitan, when deleting Message Threads (All messages from a contact),  hold the option key while clicking the X to avoid having to confirm deletion.

Comment: Option and Command don't do anything for me on OS X. Perhaps you meant to vote up the Control Key answer? That works for me... http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229715/5472

Comment: which version? I'm on El Capitan and control does nothing, but Option does!

Comment: Wow - thanks for the update and confirmation. There must be settings that can be different since you're seeing it work. Thanks!

Comment: Just added an edit - I tested this on a different macbook air the other day and it worked the same so I started wondering why it was different for you, then I realized we were talking about different things - deleting message threads vs deleting individual messages

Comment: Good catch and good point!